# inline html5 video on iphone

Tags: iphone, html, user-interface, video

I want to play an HTML5 video on the iPhone but whenever I try to, the iPhone automatically pops out in fullscreen when the video '.play()' is called. How do I play the video inline without the iPhone changing the UI of it like these:

http://www.easy-bits.com/iphone-inline-video-autostart

http://www.takeyourdose.com/en (When you click "Start the 360 experience")

Edit: Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>iPhone Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('vid').play()">Start</button>

        <video id="vid">
            <source src="/videos/tutorial.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Answer (score 8):

I'm working on a solution to this until Apple allows the "webkit-playsinline" to actually play inline.

I started a library here: https://github.com/newshorts/InlineVideo

It's very rough, but the basic gist is that you "seek" through the video instead of playing it outright. So instead of calling:

```
video.play()
```

You instead set a loop using request animation frame or setInterval, then set the:

```
video.currentTime = __FRAME_RATE__
```

So the whole thing might look like in your html:

```
<video controls width="300">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">
</video>
<canvas></canvas>
<button>Play</button>
```

and your js (make sure to include jquery)

```
var video = $('video')[0];
var canvas = $('canvas')[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var lastTime = Date.now();
var animationFrame;
var framesPerSecond = 25;
function loop() {
    var time = Date.now();
    var elapsed = (time - lastTime) / 1000;

    // render
    if(elapsed >= ((1000/framesPerSecond)/1000)) {
        video.currentTime = video.currentTime + elapsed;
        $(canvas).width(video.videoWidth);
        $(canvas).height(video.videoHeight);
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
        lastTime = time;
    }

    // if we are at the end of the video stop
    var currentTime = (Math.round(parseFloat(video.currentTime)*10000)/10000);
    var duration = (Math.round(parseFloat(video.duration)*10000)/10000);
    if(currentTime >= duration) {
        console.log('currentTime: ' + currentTime + ' duration: ' + video.duration);
        return;
    }

    animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

$('button').on('click', function() {
  video.load();
  loop();
});
```

http://codepen.io/newshorts/pen/yNxNKR

The real driver for Apple changing this will be the recent release of webGL for ios devices enabled by default. Basically there are going to be a whole bunch of people looking to use video textures. technically right now, that can't be done.

Answer (score 7):

On IOS10 / Safari 10 you can now add the `playsinline` property to the HTML5 Video element, and it will just play inline.

Comment: And on iOS 8-9 you can use [iphone-inline-video](https://github.com/bfred-it/iphone-inline-video/) as a polyfill

Answer (score 3):

If you create an audio element and a video element, you can play the audio via user interaction and then seek the video, rendering it to a canvas. This is something quick that I came up with (tested on iPhone iOS 9)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
var video = document.createElement('video');

function onFrame(){
    ctx.drawImage(video,0,0,426,240);
    video.currentTime = audio.currentTime;
    requestAnimationFrame(onFrame);
}

function playVideo(){
    var i = 0;
    function ready(){
        i++;
        if(i == 2){
            audio.play();
            onFrame();
        }
    }
    video.addEventListener('canplaythrough',ready);
    audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough',ready);

    audio.src = video.src = "http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_10mb.mp4";

    audio.load();
    video.load();
}
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/kkirby/pen/xVGXKb)

[Test Page](http://codepen.io/kkirby/debug/xVGXKb)

Comment: Would this not load the source file twice?

Comment: @yckart, no. The video is cached on the first load. I thought it would load twice too. I checked the network inspector to see that it only actually loaded the video once and the second request was served from cache.

Comment: This works! If you prefer a more comprehensive solution, try [iphone-inline-video](https://github.com/bfred-it/iphone-inline-video) (disclosure: I wrote it). It's basically the same concept but it also takes care of events and makes it seamless.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for writing this as an answer instead of a comment on the main thread, but I apparently do not have enough reputation points to comment!

Anyways, I am also looking to do exactly the same thing as the OP.

I noticed that there is a particular library, [krpano](http://krpano.com/), coupled with the [krpano videoplayer plugin](http://krpano.com/plugins/videoplayer/) that allows for video to be played on iPhone INLINE! Some demos of this in action can be found here: http://krpano.com/video/

While I would prefer a simple 2D video example over these crazy panorama videos, this is the closest I have found while scouring the web. From what I can tell, they use a normal  element not attached to the document:

```
var v = document.querySelector('video');

// remove from document
v.parentNode.removeChild(v); 

// touch anywhere to play
document.ontouchstart = function () {
  v.play();
}
```

Video element before it's removed:

```
<video playsinline webkit-playsinline preload="auto" crossorigin="anonymous" src="http://www.mediactiv.com/video/Milano.mp4" loop style="transform: translateZ(0px);"></video>
```

But that alone doesn't seem to be enough: when the video is played, it still goes fullscreen.

How do they manage to prevent the video from going fullscreen?

---

EDIT: After looking at both examples it looked like they both were leveraging the canvas element to render the video, so I went ahead and whipped up a demo showing off video rendering thru the canvas element. While the demo works great, it fails to deliver on iPhone (even tho the video element is completely removed from the DOM!) -- the video still jumps to full screen. I'm thinking the next step would be to apply these same principles to a WebGL canvas (that's what the krpano examples are doing), but in the meantime maybe this demo will spark some ideas in others...

http://jakesiemer.com/projects/video/index.htm

Comment: Chris J, I also think that your first example works because that particular library actually DECODES the video stream in real-time via JavaScript (instead of leveraging the Browser/OS's built-in decoder).

This is similar to [Broadway.js](https://github.com/mbebenita/broadway), which also coincidentally works on iPhone, albeit, the framerate seems really wacky, and the audio doesn't seem to sync particularly well. Example here: http://mbebenita.github.io/Broadway/foxDemo.html